# Recursion Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme

I have a formula, (2^n)-1, and I need to convert it to a recursion function, I tried several times to rewrite it, but I'm still struggling. What is wrong with my code?

```
(define fnum(n)
    (if (= n 0) 0
        (- ( * 2 (fnum (- n 1)) 1)))

(fnum (- n 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this ([working example](https://repl.it/repls/InfiniteNeighboringMouse)):

```
(define pow
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 0)
      1
      (* 2 (pow (- n 1))))))

(display (- (pow 5) 1))
```

It is clear that you should split the powering part with the minus 1 step which is going to be performed afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the recursion from the substraction:

```
(define (parent-nodes-helper n)
  (if (= n 0) 
      0
      (* 2 (parent-nodes-helper (- n 1)))))

;;; Number of parent nodes in a perfect balanced binary tree
(define (parent-nodes depth)
  (- (parent-nodes-helper depth) 1))
```

Now. The helper can be made local to `fnum` and even be implemented as named `let` and then you can add `acc` parameter to hold the result so that the multiplication doesn't need to be done after each recusion ends. Here is a how I would do it:

```
;;; Number of parent nodes in a perfect balanced binary tree
(define (parent-nodes depth)
  (let loop ((n depth) (acc 1))
    (if (zero? n) 
        (- acc 1)
        (loop (- n 1) (* acc 2)))))
```

It's common to call an iterative tail recursion in named let `loop`, but I could have kept the name `parent-nodes-helper` or whatever I found fitting. It's just a name.